# How exactly do I show a view using reactiveui?

Tags: c#, mvvm, reactiveui

In my WPF application I need to get View based on MyViewModel and show it using ReactiveUI and can't figure out how to do it.

So long all got is this lines:

```
Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new MyView(), typeof(IViewFor<MyViewModel>));
            var ViewModel = (MyViewModel)Locator.CurrentMutable.GetService(typeof(MyViewModel));
```

Then I should use some "Router" but what exactly is this?

Answer (score 3):

I am going to use samples from the book You, I and Reactive UI. Here is the GIT repository https://github.com/kentcb/YouIandReactiveUI

In terms of using the RoutedViewHost WPF control you can do the following (which you seem to be wanting to use based on what you mentioned)

First I have some sort of boot strapper class where I do my Splat registrations. On that I will have create a object of RoutingState. This is used by the RoutedViewHost.

```
    protected Bootstrapper()
    {
        RegisterMyDIStuff();
        this.Router = new RoutingState();

        resolver.RegisterConstant<IScreen>(this);

        this
            .Router
            .NavigateAndReset
            .Execute(new StartViewModel())
            .Subscribe()
            .DisposeWith(this.disposable);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public RoutingState Router { get; }
```

All views must implement the interface IViewFor and be registered in Splat. Eg:
            resolver.Register(() => new LoginView(), typeof(IViewFor));

In your XAML file declare the RoutedViewHost

```
 <rxui:RoutedViewHost
            x:Name="routedViewHost"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

Then in your code behind for the view's code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   this.routedViewHost.Router = BootStrapper.Router;
}
```

Then you View Models have to derive off **IRoutableViewModel**

```
    public MainViewModel(IScreen hostScreen = null)
    {
        this.HostScreen = hostScreen ?? Locator.Current.GetService<IScreen>();
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public string UrlPathSegment => "Main";

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IScreen HostScreen { get; }
```

Then when you want to navigate to another ViewModel's View you can:

```
        await this.HostScreen.Router.NavigateAndReset.Execute(new LogoutViewModel());
```

Comment: Please explain how to declare RoutedViewHost in the XAML. I try to define rxui namespase:  `xmlns:rxui="ReactiveUI"`. But then I get an error: The name "RoutedViewHost" does not exist in the namespace "ReactiveUI".

Comment: Solved. Just had to add ReactiveUI.WPF reference.